# Switch java version on Win10 - issue on register key

Tags: java, java-8, windows-10

I have to switch between Java 7 and Java 8 on Windows 10.

I have both installed:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
```

In my PATH there is a generic path (which contains links to java executables). This is the only java value in all eviroment variables:

```
Path=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;..
```

When I want to run Java 8, I create 3 real links to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91` (with command `mklink /H [link] [origin]`):

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe   >> C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\javapath\java.exe  
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe  >> C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\javapath\javaw.exe 
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaws.exe >> C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\javapath\javaws.exe
```

With this configuration **it works**.

But, when I want to run Java 7, I create 3 real links to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe   >> C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javapath\java.exe  
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe  >> C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javapath\javaw.exe 
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaws.exe >> C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javapath\javaws.exe
```

When I try to run java, **it doesn't work!** I get the following error:

```
Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion' 
has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

There is a workaround, but I don't like it much. I can work with Java 7 only this way:

1. Remove `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;` from %PATH%
2. Add `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;` to %PATH%

I don't like this solution because it is different from the previous configuration, and because I have everytime to remove manually the value from PATH.

Comment: Is it just a copy-and-paste issue or did you really link to the non-existent ..\jre7\bin\ **javapath** \java.exe?

Comment: This is the full command, and it works: `mklink /H C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe   "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"`

Comment: The problem is that java.exe tries to find its JRE directory first by seeing if it's where it's started from. Since the javapath directory doesn't contain the JRE, it then looks for it in the Registry and finds the wrong one. If you add the JRE7\bin directory to the path, java.exe will find it. You don't have to remove the javapath directory; just make sure jre7\bin comes first, e.g. `path %programfiles%\Java\jre7\bin;%path%` will suffice.

Comment: ok but, this way, everytime I have to switch JAva version, my batch add another path at the beginning of %PATH%; otherwise I must manually change it

Comment: I know, it's not an ideal solution - that's why I didn't put it as an answer.

Comment: why you need to run java7 binaries?

Comment: I work with a software that use java. The software is an `.exe` file. If it's a batch I could open it and change something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice to know what Oracle's recommended way is, but couldn't find this information. The following might be a reasonable <strike>hack</strike> workaround (I've used a similar method in the past).

Create a junction (or a symbolic link):

```
mklink /j "C:\Program Files\Java\jre" "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102"
```

Then remove `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` from your `PATH` and replace it with `C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin`.

Now, whenever you want to switch to Java 7, just do:

```
rd "C:\Program Files\Java\jre"
mklink /j "C:\Program Files\Java\jre" "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"
```

This works because when you now type `java` it will find it (from the PATH) in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin\java.exe`. The executable knows which directory it's in, and looks there for the other files (jars, DLLs etc). Since `jre` is now an alias for `jre7`, it will find the right ones. And because it finds them, it doesn't look in the registry.

You can, of course, create a batch file or shortcut icon containing the command to switch between the two versions.

Comment: The difference between your and mine config is that you create a `mklink /J` for a folder, and I create a `milink /H` for executable files. Sadly, your solution has the same error on Registry Key. The same with `mklink /H` on a folder. I don't know why, but having the real folder in the PATH instead of a link makes all differences.

Comment: @Radioleao `mklink /h` doesn't work on folders afaik, you'd need to use `mklink /d`. You might want to try that.

Comment: I've tried the 4 configurations: hard link on files - hard link on folder - symlink on files - symlink on folder.

Comment: For folders you can only use `mklink /j` or `mklink /d`. And it does work differently to your solution of using `mklink /h` on files. The essential difference is that when linking to a folder the executable can find all its dependencies in the same folder, so it doesn't look in the registry.

Comment: I tested this solution with Windows 10 and Java 6, 7, and 8 (JDKs) and it worked smoothly. Interestingly, the best variant was `mklink jdk pathToActualJDK` *without* using `/D`. Then, the link itself is treated as file, but resolving paths through it still works, i.e. adding `jdk\bin` to the `PATH` allows finding `java.exe`, etc. of the linked actual jdk. The advantage of not using `/D` is, that you can do a simple `del jdk` to get rid of the link, without `del` trying to delete recursively, as `jdk` it treated as file.

Comment: @Holger How is your registry? Can you tell me what registry keys you have under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment`?

Comment: @Radioleao: it contained references to some of my 1.8 installations, but to prove that they are irrelevant when linking the jdk folder, I deleted the entire `JavaSoft` branch and it still works. The key point really is that you have to link the entire jre or jdk folder rather than the executables.

Comment: I tested with this, is there something more that I forgot o I can check? `mklink /D C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin"`

Comment: @Radioleao I think the problem is that you linked `javapath` (which is on the PATH) to `jre7\bin`. So now the PATH finds java.exe in `javapath`, and java.exe now looks at where it lives and thinks the parent directory (which contains dependencies in some other subdirectories) is `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java`. But there are no other subdirectories there. You need to link to the `jre` directory and set the PATH to `jre\bin`, and not take shortcuts by linking directly to `jre\bin`.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou IT worked with both C:\Program Files\Java\jre and C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin in my path. Do you think it will work even with further java update? We will see...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% but I believe you may have to set the JAVA_HOME variable to the version you want to use also.

Comment: Until today, it has always worked without JAVA_HOME, Can it be old stuff? Anyway I tried **SET JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jre7** and nothing changed.

Comment: Sorry, I should have looked closer. JAVA_HOME is for JDK. JRE_HOME applies to the JRE

Comment: No chages. But with further issue, it worked if I change the value of %PATH% environment variable, but this is not the best solution. I'm going to update my request.

Comment: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javaexe.html#MULTIPLES

might help you a little more. It looks like there is a java in system32 also, so if that is first in your path, that will look at the registry to decide which version to run. Maybe switch your path values around?

Comment: I never set `JAVA_HOME` nor `JRE_HOME` in the last twenty years of using Java.